# Does my server have PHP Sockets?

Tags: php, sockets

Is there anyway to tell if my server has PHP Sockets?
The script I'm using says it needs them.
I have installed PHP5.

Thanks.

Comment: The fastest way is to.. you know... try and see if it works?

Comment: But the thing is I have no idea what PHP sockets even are... is it included in php 5? Commands to test it?

Comment: Use `phpinfo()`, surprisingly it is at the section "sockets"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant way to programmatically check for [PHP Sockets](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) support is to use the [`get_loaded_extentions()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) method:

```
if (in_array('sockets', get_loaded_extensions()) {
    // continue
} else {
    die ('No socket support.');
}
```

Your script probably does it this way too. You can also inspect the output from `phpinfo();` for the Sockets extension.

Comment: @CoryChassagne If the answer was helpful, consider accepting it using the green checkmark. It will be more helpful for others this way. If you particularly liked my answer, you can also upvote it once you gain the privilege.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you have sockets by using the following code;

```
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
```

You can find more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project!